# How to prevent selection change on a NgPrime

Tags: angular, primeng, prime-tree

I'm using a [tree](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/tree) of PrimeNg.

I use it in a "master/details" pattern: the tree allow to select which node I want to edit, once selected, a form on its right allow to edit the selected node. The user has to click on a button to save the changes.

This works great, but if the user has edited something and then navigates to another node, the changes get lost. I would like to display a [confirmation dialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/confirmdialog) to inform the user he didn't save his changes and offer him the chance to cancel the selection.

Currently I've the following :

```
    <p-tree
      class="h-full"
      [value]="organizations"
      selectionMode="single"
      [(selection)]="selectedOrganization"
      [loading]="(loading | async) ?? true"
      loadingIcon="fa-light fa-spinner-third fa-spin"
      styleClass="custom-tree"
      (onNodeSelect)="onOrganizationSelect($event)"></p-tree>
```

and in the event listener, I've the following:

```
  onOrganizationSelect(event: any) {
    if (!this.form.pristine) {
      this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'Your changes have not been saved and will be lost, are you sure you want to change?',
        accept: () => {
          this.updateForm();
        },
        reject: () => {
          //How to cancel the change? Especially since this is a callback?
        },
      });
    } else {
      this.updateForm();
    }
  }
```

But I don't know how to cancel the PrimeNg Tree selection change, any suggestion? I can imagine that I could store some "previousSelection" and restore it, but that means that during the dialog is shown, the selected item is already changed?

Comment: That is trivially implemented using [navigation guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) if you can refactor the component to work in a routed way.

Comment: @skink I probably poorly expressed myself: It's all inside the same component, so the navigation guard has no chance of intercepting it.

Comment: @skink I tried your approach to see how it would work, but I'm not sure how a navigation guard would know if a form in a component has been touched?

Comment: Did you have a look to the onNodeUnselect event? You could programmatically store selected values and before unselecting node do your confirmation

Comment: Sorry, I may have worded my comment wrongly — what I meant was that if you can afford refactoring this big component into the `master` (with the tree and a router outlet) and `detail` (with the form) components, then register them as routes, e.g. `/organizations` pointing to the `master` and a child route `/:id` pointing to the `detail`, then it will be easy to implement the rest.

Comment: but anyway, how do you detect in a navigation guard, the status of the form of the current detail?

Comment: The `CanDeactivate` guard receives a handle to the component, which you can then call to determine whether there are changes or not.